# How to insert a variable in a variable in a random place?

Tags: bash, sed, perl, ksh

**Q:** How can I insert variable $b to a truly random place in variable $a?

Example INPUT variable content:

```
$ echo $a
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
$ echo $b
ZZ
```

OUTPUT

```
$ ./somemagicscript.sh
árvíztűrő tüköZZrfúrógép
$ ./somemagicscript.sh
árvíztűrő tükörfúrZZógép
$ ./somemagicscript.sh
árvíztűrZZő tükörfúrógép
$ ./somemagicscript.sh
árvíztűrő tZZükörfúrógép
```

**UPDATE:** The current answers are not perfectly good since under OpenBSD it sometimes places a "�" character besides the inserted variable. :\

Maybe than when the inserted variable is next to a multi-byte character..

Comment: `sed "s/.\{$(($RANDOM%${#a}))\}/&$b/" <<< $a`

Comment: If bsd `sed` and `awk` are not utf-8 aware, then will an answer in another language, such as python, be of use?

Comment: Re BSD editing: Try `sed "s/\(.\{$(($RANDOM%${#a}))\}\)/\1$b/" <<< $a`

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "s/.\{$(($RANDOM%${#a}))\}/&$b/" <<< $a
```

where:

- `$RANDOM` pseudo-random value from 0 to `$RAND_MAX` (usually *0x7fff* == *32767*)
- `${#a}` length of target string
- `$((...%...))` outputs the resedue from dividing
- `.{n}` match first n characters of input string
- `s/.../&$b/` substitutes pattern match by themselves + `$b`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers give solutions for sed and awk. If your sed and awk don't support multibyte characters, there's still a good chance that your bash does support them, so here is a pure-bash solution.

First we choose a random number between 0 and the length of the string `$a`, inclusive, so that the string `$b` can be inserted between any two characters of `$a`, or before the first, or after the last. This is stored in `mid`. Then we create a string consisting of (using pseudocode) `a[0..mid-1] + b + a[mid..$]` (indexing starts at 0).

```
$ cat ./multi
#!/bin/bash
a='árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép'
b='ZZ'
len=${#a}
echo "a is ${a} len is ${len}"
mid=$(((len + 1) * $RANDOM / 32767))
c="${a:0:$mid}${b}${a:$mid}"
echo "$c"

$ ./multi
a is árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép len is 22
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógéZZp
$ ./multi
a is árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép len is 22
árvízZZtűrő tükörfúrógép
$ ./multi
a is árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép len is 22
árvíztűrő tükörZZfúrógép
$ ./multi
a is árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép len is 22
ZZárvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

Answer (score 0):

an attempt in awk:

```
awk "{srand(); i=int(rand()*length(\$0)); print substr(\$0,0,i)\"${b}\"substr(\$0,i)}" <<< $a
```

Comment: this one is good too, but Costat was faster, sorry

Comment: Costas' is nicer and shorter (and he was faster). but at least i tricked himinto submitting an *answer* not just a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl (suitable for a shell script):

```
perl -CSA -e '$_=shift; substr($_,int(rand(1+length)),0,shift); print' "$a" "$b"
```

Note the 1+length different positions here: at the start of the string and after each character.

ETA: And yes, the `-CSA` specifies that command line arguments and standard output (and other standard file handles) use UTF-8 (multibyte).